# Ionic 7 - Ion-select component example of floating label does not render in browser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic7

I'm developing an app using ionic 7 and angular.

I'm trying to use the ion-select component with floating label:
`<ion-select label="Floating label" label-placement="floating">`

I'm using *exactly the same example* published in the ionic official documentation. However, I don't get the expected output when rendering the page in either *firefox* or *chrome*.
Am I missing anything?
(I note that other ionic components I'm using render as expected)

The code I'm using is as published on https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select
(section label placement):

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-select label="Default label" placeholder="Favorite Fruit">
      <ion-select-option value="apple">Apple</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="banana">Banana</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="orange">Orange</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-select label="Fixed label" label-placement="fixed" placeholder="Favorite fruit">
      <ion-select-option value="apple">Apple</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="banana">Banana</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="orange">Orange</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-select label="Stacked label" label-placement="stacked">
      <ion-select-option value="apple">Apple</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="banana">Banana</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="orange">Orange</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-select label="Floating label" label-placement="floating">
      <ion-select-option value="apple">Apple</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="banana">Banana</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="orange">Orange</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The expected output is:

[image]

However, the actual output I get is:
(Stacked and floating labels missing)

[image]

My app.module.ts looks as follows:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
    
    import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
    
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Drivers } from '@ionic/storage';
    import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
    import * as CordovaSQLiteDriver from 'localforage-cordovasqlitedriver';

    import { ExampleComponent } from './pages/example/example.component'; //Added to try MK's example (see post comments)
    
    // Added FormsModule as suggested by MK (see post comments)
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, FormsModule,
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
        name: '__mydb',
        driverOrder: [CordovaSQLiteDriver._driver, Drivers.IndexedDB, Drivers.LocalStorage]
      })],
      providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that you've imported everything correct in the the module?
How does your app.module.ts look like?

Comment: Thanks Marian, I have included the content of my app.module.ts at the end of my initial post.

Comment: I've created a fork of the official Stackblitz project: 'https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjwz4y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts' it looks like you are missing the import of the forms module in the '@NgModule'. Let me know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: @Marian It did not fix the issue (I've updated the app.module.ts content in the post). I'll try to create a new project equivalent to your fork and see what happens... will let you know